# dynamic translations for Rails built-in i18n system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

I'd like to switch my Rails 3.2 app from using static views and static translation files (in config/locales/*.yml) to a "dynamic" version - that is: view's template will be loaded from the DB through the new model/controller, and yml translations will do the same (so users/admins will have control over some views).

I know how to render these templates, but I can't find a way to use my new translations instead of old static ones, with minimal (or none) template code changes. 
Is it possible to "overwrite" those yml lines?

How can I then "restore" the default values? (or simply this "overwriting" should be only for a single use inside the method)

PS Ideally it should merge my dynamic translations with the static ones, so I don't need to duplicate all my existing more-or-less constant lines.

Comment: just check http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3

Comment: Rajesh, that's not exactly what I look for. I don't need automatic translation of the views, etc. Simple addition of a couple lines to existing translation would be nice instead. 

I found an interesting standard method 
`I18n.backend.store_translations(:en, {my_contr: {form: {section: "AAA"}}})`
But this makes the changes permanent, so I can't rollback to the default yaml, and overwrite different lines for the next rendered template.